# How can I optimize Teemo's role in a teamfight?

Tags: league-of-legends

I prefer to play Teemo as an AP with Attack Speed items such as Nashor's Tooth and I was wondering what his role is in a teamfight. He doesn't do a lot of damage with anything but his mushrooms. So what should I do during a teamfight? Play like an AD carry, an AP carry, or make a escape route if we start to lose? Also, should I concentrate on one person or spread my poison around? And should I use mushrooms to hit lots of people or save them for running? I have to be careful as I'm very fragile.

Comment: Short answer: nothing.  Your job is to take down peoples' health before the team fight with rampant shrooms and to blind the ADC.  Then you pray your team can do the rest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to play Teemo (I've seen pure AP, AP/AS, AD carry, support, etc.), although the different styles often have several points in common.

**Things you want to do regardless of build**

- *Prioritize targets* - Teemo's Blinding Shot (Q) is a ridiculously strong crowd control effect, but only when used on the proper champions. Blind has little to no effect if you target AP carries or tanks, but it can completely shut down AD champions (Jax, Fiora, and most AD carries)
- *Keep shrooms up* - Teemo's shrooms are amazing, regardless of build. Not only do they provide vision and serve as an early-warning system, they also have a great CC slowing effect. I've seen several support Teemos help their team to disengage by placing shrooms as they retreat.

AP Teemo in particular should drop shrooms as often as possible outside of combat, they have great scaling with AP and more vision never hurts. However, the small cast range on shrooms means that shrooming during teamfights will generally be a defensive maneuver. Be sure to drop one or two under your AD carry if you suspect that you will be initiated on.

The blind is one thing that I cannot stress enough. I have seen countless Teemos blind the enemy AP carry in an effort to score a kill while the enemy Jax or Fiora rips holes through the team. Do not waste your blind.

You won't be using your shrooms all too often during teamfights unless they engage on you. However, if you notice an enemy standing open in one spot (generally the AD carry), feel free to drop a shroom if you think you can do without too much risk. AP Teemo's damage during fights will come mostly from sustained damage on his Toxic Shot and burst from his Blinding Shot.

Comment: +1 for mentioning to not waste blind. Cannot stress that point enough.

Answer (score 2):

> I prefer to play Teemo as an AP with Attack Speed [...]
>
> He doesn't do a lot of damage [...]

I disagree on this point.  Teemo's damage, especially in an AS/AP build, is very significant.  Play him like an AD carry, attacking whomever you safely can.  Remember to use blind as well as poison; focus on blinding the ADC when possible, but a bruiser assaulting your carry is also a good choice.

> should I concentrate on one person or spread my poison around?

Focus on whoever you can safely hit.

> And should I use mushrooms to hit lots of people or save them for running?

Since you're building AP, you want to hit as many people as possible.  If you find your mushrooms getting picked off from oracles/pink wards, it may be possible to sneak in and drop them right at your opponents feet.

> I have to be careful as I'm very fragile.

Consider building a Frozen Mallet on Teemo.  The perma-slow and extra health compliment his existing kit very well.